# SessionEndingEvent not getting called

Tags: c#, .net, events, logout, shutdown

this is my C# code:

```
    void main()
    {
        SystemEvents.SessionEnding += new SessionEndingEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnding);
    }

    void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Reason);
    }
```

Somehow, there is no output. Any ideas why?

Comment: if one of the answers solves your problem, feel free and upvote / accept the answer

Comment: I sure will. My problem has not been solved yet. The Application i am trying to use this in is a Windows Service.

Comment: okay! services behave not like desktop apps.

Comment: have edited my answer so that you can accomplish your goals.

Comment: A service doesn't have a console.  You can't *see* the output.  You must have noticed that before?

Comment: Sure, i am using a Log function for that ;-) Was just writing this quick-short example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx (Example 2) pretty much explains everything about SystemEvents in windows services.

Answer (score 0):

Accorind to the [remarks section in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx):

> If you are using SessionEnding in a Windows form to detect a system logoff or reboot, there is no deterministic way to decide whether the Closing event will fire before this event.

So you should not rely on this event or somehow process `Closing` event to achieve your needs.

**Update**. More important thing:

> Console applications do not raise the SessionEnding event.

Comment: Do you know if this also applies to Windows Services?